# Two subclasses have the same code but different baseclasses. How can I ensure reuse?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am lazy I don't want to write the same code twice, so how can I avoid it in this case?
I have nodes in a tree some of them has a member _key like this:

```
struct node_base {
    virtual void foo()=0;
    virtual ~node_base() {}
}

template<typename Key>
struct node_key: public node_base {
    node_key(Key k): _key(k) {}
    virtual ~node_key() {}

protected:
    Key _key;
};
```

Now I have two types of child nodes one which inherits from node_key and one which only inherits from node_base

```
struct no_key {};

template<typename Key, typename Data>
struct child: public node_key<Key> {
…
    void foo() {
    //do something with _data
    }
protected:
    Data _data;
}

template<typename Data>
struct child<no_key,Data>: public node_base {
…
    void foo() {
    //do something with _data
    }
protected:
    Data _data;
}
```

However at you see I write foo twice and it is identical in both cases. Can I do something to ensure reuse?
The advantage of node_key is that I can have a pointer

```
node_key<int> *p=new child<int,int>
…
p->foo();
```

and it will fail at compile time if p=new child< int > which is fine. I can also have a pointer.

```
node_base *p=get_a_child();
p->foo();
```

More about my tree here:
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100013861179843

Comment: You could instead specialize `node_key` so that it omits `_key` member when its template argument is `no_key`. Then you wouldn't need to specialize every `child` separately.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I think you are right, but I have to do some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chose the base class of `child` using a traits struct:

```
struct no_key {};

template<typename Key, typename Data>
struct child_base_traits {
    typedef node_key<Key> type;
};

template<typename Data>
struct child_base_traits<no_key, Data> {
    typedef node_base type;
};

template<typename Key, typename Data>
struct child: public typename child_base_traits<Key,Data>::type {
    void foo() {
    //do something with _data
    }
protected:
    Data _data;
};
```

Or, as @Igor suggested, just specialize `node_key<no_key>`:

```
template<>
struct node_key<no_key> : node_base {} ;
```